# ERROR: column <name> is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type character varying

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-aurora-serverless

I am reading a csv file export from MS SQL db table and trying to insert the data into PostgreSQL (Aurora Serverless) db. When I created the equivalent table in the PostgreSQL database I used column type mapping that I [found online](http://www.sqlines.com/sql-server-to-postgresql) to map the datetime (MS SQL) to timestamp(3) (PostgreSQL) type. However, when I try to insert a record into the Postgres db I get that error:

```
Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (\'10000002\', \'2020-11-22 00:00:00\')\nRETURNING * was aborted: 
ERROR: column "Date" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type character varying\n 
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.\n  Position: 37  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
```

My MS SQL table schema:

```
ID: varchar(20)
Date: datetime
```

csv file contains:

```
10000002, 2020-11-22 00:00:00
10000003, 2020-11-22 00:00:00
...
```

PostgreSQL table schema/create statement:

```
CREATE table my_table
(
    "ID"                      varchar(20)  not null,
    "Date"                  timestamp(3)
);
```

In the error message, the hint says that I may have to cast the expression but I am not sure how I am supposed to do that or if that is the best resolution in my case.

I am using the following script to load the data from csv file and push it to the PostgreSQL db:

```
import boto3
import csv
rds_client = boto3.client('rds-data')

def batch_execute_statement(sql, sql_parameter_sets, transaction_id=None):
    parameters = {
        'secretArn': db_credentials_secrets_store_arn,
        'database': database_name,
        'resourceArn': db_cluster_arn,
        'sql': sql,
        'parameterSets': sql_parameter_sets
    }
    if transaction_id is not None:
        parameters['transactionId'] = transaction_id
    response = rds_client.batch_execute_statement(**parameters)
    return response

transaction = rds_client.begin_transaction(
    secretArn=db_credentials_secrets_store_arn,
    resourceArn=db_cluster_arn,
    database=database_name)


sql = "INSERT INTO rigs_latest VALUES (:ID, :Date;"
parameter_set = []


with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        entry = [
            {'name': 'ID', 'value': {'stringValue': row['ID']}},
            {'name': 'Date', 'value': {'stringValue': row['Date']}}
        ]
        parameter_set.append(entry)

response = batch_execute_statement(
    sql, parameter_set, transaction['transactionId'])
```

**UPDATE**:

If I use the Query Editor to insert a record such as `insert into rigs_latest values (10000002, '2020-11-22 00:00:00');` it works without a problem

[image]

That suggests that there is something wrong with the code itself

Comment: How do you load your data in the table? Please show us the relevant part of your code.

Comment: I should have done that, sorry. I updated my question with the script I am using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending some more time researching, I found that we can specify a `typeHint` for each `entry` in the `parameter_set`. According to the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds-data.html#RDSDataService.Client.execute_statement) the `typeHint` allows us to specify that the parameter is of time `TIMESTAMP` like so:

```
...
    entry = [
        {'name': 'ID', 'value': {'stringValue': row['ID']}},
        {'name': 'Date','typeHint': 'TIMESTAMP', 'value': {'stringValue': row['Date']}}
    ]
    parameter_set.append(entry)
...
```

I guess that helps the interpreter figure out that we want the `Date` parameter to be of type `TIMESTAMP`

Comment: I found this issue with some GoLang code. I used {
    Name:     aws.String("submitted"),
    TypeHint: aws.String("TIMESTAMP"),
    Value: &rdsdataservice.Field{
     StringValue: aws.String(submitted),
    },
   },